# Sending Data to the front end in Express and accessing it

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to express and am pretty confused on how I should access data on the front-end side,

I have the following code

```
exports.init = function(req, res){
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    //res.send();  
    var userId = req.user._id  
    res.render('account/usernotes');
  }
  else {
    res.render('signup/index', {
      oauthMessage: '',
      oauthTwitter: !!req.app.config.oauth.twitter.key,      
      oauthFacebook: !!req.app.config.oauth.facebook.key,
      oauthGoogle: !!req.app.config.oauth.google.key
    });
  }
};
```

I want to send UserId to the view so that I can access it so that I can fetch data using it, but so far using send(); renders the value of the data to the front-end, so how do I access it.  I am guessing

```
res.render('account/usernotes',req.user._id);
```

should work but how do I access the data after this ?

Comment: Tell me one thing Is your page rendering successfully ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I use Jade/EJS templates, it is something like this:

```
res.render('account/usernotes', {userid: req.user._id});
```

In jade file:

```
p #{userid}
```

In ejs file you can do:

```
<%=userid%>
```

Comment: Thanks, I actually figured out  it before this but you gave the right answer.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the way to send data from server to client.

Here is your server side code.

```
res.render('index', { data1: 'Hello', data2: 'World'  });
```

Get data on your view which is index.ejs.

```
<h1> <%= data1 + ' ' + data2 %> </h1>
```

For Further Reference See [This](http://embeddedjs.com/getting_started.html)